# unable to see 'dependencies' inside zipkin UI dependencies tab

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin, open-telemetry

I am using opentelemetry java agent to send the traces from a java application to zipkin and i am able to see all the traces as expected. But when I click on "Dependencies" tab in zipkin UI, i dont see any dependency metrics on it. Can someone please tell me why i am not able see them? Does it require any additional plugins or agents?